# Angular return to old parent route from child route without building everything again

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Assume I have a component which is called by route 'students' and rendered in student list component. Here I send a request to load all student names. When clicked on student I redirect to ':id' child route which shows detailed description of a student. Then when I press back button in browser ,it redirects back to 'students' route where a request sent again to load all students. 
Question: is it possible in Angular to not destroy parent route so  when returned from child route it wont build again. I need that for performance improvement.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please add more detail so that we can actually give you a legit answer that fits your case.

Comment: You can also search for "custom reuse strategy", but for network requests using a shared service to keep the data is the better way anyway.

Comment: you can use RouteReuseStrategy to reuse rendered component

Comment: thanks a lot ! I will try to add it to the project.